# Centering a header in Deluxe Table

Tags: tables, pdftex

I would like to center the subheader "LightCurve Derived Orbital Parameter" in the deluxetable without affecting the width of the headers of each column.

As seen in the image below, the subheader defines the width of the first column which causes the headers to spill out of the page. How would I achieve this in a deluxe table? The code is given below. Thanks!

Please find below a "minimal working example" code. Please make sure to download .cls file to have it run. You can download the file here: http://www.cita.utoronto.ca/~matzner/svc/tex/aastex.cls

[image: aastex]

```
\documentclass[manuscript]{aastex}  
\begin{document}   
\begin{deluxetable}{ccccrrc}

\tablewidth{0pc}
\tabletypesize{\footnotesize}
\tablecaption{}
\tablecolumns{7}
\tablehead{
\colhead{Parameter} & \colhead{KIC 230919} & \colhead{KIC 2576692} & \colhead{KIC 3230787} & \colhead{KIC 3439031} & \colhead{KIC 3449540} & \colhead{KIC 4847832}  \\ 
}   
\startdata
\textit{LightCurve Derived Orbital Parameters}  \\
\textit{P} (days) \\
$T_{transit}$ \\
i (deg) \\
e \\
$\omega$ (deg) \\
$\Omega_1$ \\
$\Omega_2$ \\

\enddata
\end{deluxetable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please where does `deluxetable` come from? Can you please give us a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Ah, ok. Here's a MWE (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23725837/aastex52.zip) The tex file is "sample.tex". The table mentioned in this post is Table 1 in sample.pdf. I have also left other examples of deluxe tables in the document. Hope this helps. Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: The "troubling table" is: latex_targets_params.tex which appears as \input in the sample.tex.

Comment: Please add a *complete* MWE to your question - that is one that compiles and includes `\documentclass...\end{document}`. People are more likely to help if you give them a short version of what you are trying to do that exhibits the problem. They are much less likely to follow a link that you give in order to download a zip file and then try to extract a non-minimal example from this...

Comment: Alright, updated the MWE and added link to .cls file. By the way, the zip file contains the MWE. In fact it is the most complete everything-in-one-place working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is to add a `\multicolumn{}` tag to the line that spans all the columns.

So, it would look like this:

```
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\emph{Lightcurve Derived Orbital Parameters}} \\
```

Here's the code again with the line added:

```
\documentclass[manuscript]{aastex}  
\begin{document}   
\begin{deluxetable}{ccccrrc}

\tablewidth{0pc}
\tabletypesize{\footnotesize}
\tablecaption{}
\tablecolumns{7}
\tablehead{
\colhead{Parameter} & \colhead{KIC 230919} & \colhead{KIC 2576692} & \colhead{KIC 3230787} & \colhead{KIC 3439031} & \colhead{KIC 3449540} & \colhead{KIC 4847832}  \\ 
}   
\startdata
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\emph{Lightcurve Derived Orbital Parameters}} \\
\textit{P} (days) \\
$T_{transit}$ \\
i (deg) \\
e \\
$\omega$ (deg) \\
$\Omega_1$ \\
$\Omega_2$ \\

\enddata
\end{deluxetable}
\end{document}
```

The end result looks like this: 
[image]